# Using when() to Run Multiple Ajax Functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

Using jQuery when(), I am trying to run multiple Ajax functions on a form submit, wait until they get their responses and when done, finally submit form. My code is:

```
$('form[name="regForm"]').on('submit', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.when( function () {
        ajaxOne();
        ajaxTwo();
        ajaxThree();
    }
    ).done(function() {
        $('form[name="regForm"]').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

The form gets submitted but the Ajax functions never trigger. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: is page reloading when submit occurs? Have you checked if above event gets triggered? Any errors in console?

Comment: The form does get submitted, but the Ajax functions don't get executed.

Comment: `ajaxOne` should return the promise resulting from the call. Please show the code for at least one of those functions.

Comment: provided an answer but still a mystery why your form is submitting since you prevent default...check console for errors and make sure form exists when you call this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `$.when()` incorrectly

Each ajax call promise should be an argument (or in jQuery 3+ can be array of promises)

```
$(function(){
    $('form[name="regForm"]').on('submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.when( ajaxOne(), ajaxTwo(),  ajaxThree()   
        ).done(function() {
            $('form[name="regForm"]').unbind('submit').submit();
        });
    });
});
```

This also assumes that form selector is correct and that each of the ajax functions returns a `$.ajax` promise something like

```
function ajaxOne()(
  return $.ajax({...})    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass as arguments

```
$.when.apply($, arrayOfDefferds).done(doStuff);
```

Take care of getting the responses.